# How do you decrypt Maven passwords given a key? (Command?)

Tags: maven, encryption

I was given a Maven Encrypt Key and a handful of encrypted passwords in a request.

How can I decrypt those passwords - from the commandline?  Or a plugin?

I tried looking up documentation to decrypt, but ended up getting only 'encrypt' documentation for Maven.  (It's probably just me...)  Any helpful advice would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to decrypt them?

Comment: Our passwords were reset by our app admins (protocol every x amt of time) with the request for <me> to change them once I log in.  I can log in just fine.  I want to reset all of them according to what my team has specified (which was also encrypted...).  I need to decrypt what my team specified in order to reset those passwords to those specified passwords, within the app.

Comment: I did not understand that. You can just generate a new master password and encrypt new passwords that you know with it. Are we talking about the Settings encryption here?

Comment: I don't know the new passwords.  Those are what I need to decrypt.  For example: We have several instances of FunApp.  The passwords for our team were reset by the system Admin.  I have been given the temporary passwords from the reset.  When I log in, I need to change the passwords for each instance.  What I need to change them to, however, is specific and already intended for the team.  What was specified, however, was encrypted.  I need to decrypt in order to enter them for the new password setup.

Comment: *When I log in, I need to change the passwords for each instance* That is what I don't understand. How is this related to the settings encryption feature of Maven? There is no "log-in". But... you don't need to know the previous password to create a new one. Just delete the `settings-security.xml`, generate a new one. Then generate the encrypted passwords for your new passwords with it, and put it in the `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement to know the encrypted password and found a nice utility. Details you can find it here - https://jaykhimani.blogspot.com/2019/08/decrypt-maven-passwords.html